# Apending values in google sheets add ' with the values using gspread

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@jb.ranchana/write-and-append-dataframes-to-google-sheets-in-python-f62479460cf0#:%7E:text=Once%20you%20write%20the%20data,tolist()%20before%20appending.) tutorial to append new rows to my existing dataset which is working fine except one thing that is that the code is adding ' at the start of values like this

[image]

[image]

Last two rows are the problem. I have tried converting them to string but it still shows the same output

```
try:
    merge_values = merge.values.tolist()
    gs.values_append('Merged', {'valueInputOption': 'RAW'}, {'values': merge_values})
except: 
    print('No new data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the [valueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption) to `USER_ENTERED` as this will input the data as if you typed it into the Google Sheet.

```
try:
    merge_values = merge.values.tolist()
    gs.values_append('Merged', {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, {'values': merge_values})
except: 
    print('No new data')
```

Comment: I agree with Adam, I made some tests, and when I use `RAW`, the Google Sheet values change to `'20/04/2023`. However, when I use `USER_ENTERED`, it adds the values correctly.